# showing only the filtered column in the datagridview

Tags: c#

i am a newbie and a student 
i have a windows form in which is have a datadrid view.
 i have table in sql server, i have binded with the datagrid,
in the table there is a 3 column and in which one column named date of small-date-time datatype,
i just binded the datagrid view to the table and it is showing all the rows of the three column i want to filter that. i have three column one is "name" second is "surname" and third is "date" date contains smalldatetime datatype and i want to show all the three columns but the columns which has the "date" columns as 30/12/12 if the date is 31/12/12 means the record from the previous date
sorry for the bad explanation i am weak in english
i dont know what to use here 
can i achieve this?

Comment: can you please give the code you are using that will be a great help to understand you requirement

Comment: do you want to know hoe to filter your datagridview based on date?

Comment: i dont have any code i just binded the datagrid view to the table and it is showing all the rows of the three column i want to filter that. i have three column one is name second is surname and third is date date contains smalldatetime datatype and i want to show all the three columns but the columns which has the date columns as 30/12/12 if the date is 31/12/12 means the record from the previous date

Comment: yess sir ridoy, but date column is in my datadrid i want to filter on that basis

Comment: can you share your store procedure which is fetching data?

Comment: i dont have store procedure i have tablebinding source with datagrid view

Comment: share select statement for gridview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following select statement:

```
SELECT name, surname, dateColumn FROM TBLNAME WHERE where
  CONVERT(DATE,dateColumn) =DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0)
```

Kindly replace your columns and table name accordingly

Comment: where i have to write this i am using tablebinding source for datagrid view population

Comment: are you using windows form?

Comment: bhai i got... but can you explain what you have done?
CONVERT(DATE,dateColumn) =DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0)
what is this all can you tell me how it works

Comment: CONVERT(DATE,dateColumn)  is retrieving only date of your column and
DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0) gives me previous day only date

Comment: thank you arshad bhai thanks a lot if i want the date from last two days wht i have to do?

Comment: welcome, last two days means only 29th or 29th and 30th both

Comment: 29th and 30th both
i have used this
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CONVERT(date, [date])=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE()))
but it is showing only 29th

Comment: CONVERT(DATE,[date]) >=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,2,GETDATE()),0)
  and CONVERT(DATE,[date])< CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

Comment: is yess thank you for giving knowledge
thank you very much bhai

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME BHAI PLEASE

Comment: SORRY , I was unavailable that time, i think your problem has been solved. thanks for remembering me.

Comment: arshad bhai thanks for seeing.
:)

Comment: sir how can i transfer the text from a open form textbox to the datagridview cell... i have transfer the text from selected cell to the form but can i transfer the textbox value to the cell afterward?
label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
this way i transfer the text to the next form i want to now transfer the text from that form to the cell which i have selected

Comment: it will be better to post your question..

Comment: arshad bhai this is a new question can you help me here please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302330/changing-the-current-cell-selection-of-datagridview-to-row-select

Comment: @shariq_khan , i think your question has been deleted.